# How to use expandable list view in the following scenario

Tags: android, list, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am creating an application, which has different screens for admin users and different screens for normal users. When admin logs in, screen will be displayed which consists of expandable list views. The Expandable list view header is a string array. The child items are the list of values obtained from database. Now, please let me know how can I use expandable list view in my case? Since I have different list for child views should I use many adapters? When I try to use ExpandableListAdapter, It tells me to implement some 8 methods, should I use all those if yes how? The following code snippet is what which I have now:

This is my Admin Activity class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter;

import java.util.List;


public class AdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    List<String> titleText;
   SQLiteDataBaseAdapter db;

    ExpandableListView login, android, ios, testing, java, dotNet, os, hr, others;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
        toolbar.setTitle(" Admin Screen");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        login = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewLogin);
        android = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewAndroid);
        ios = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewIos);
        testing = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewTesting);
        java = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewJava);
        dotNet = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewDotNet);
        os = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewOS);
        hr = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewHR);
        others = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewOthers);



// Lsit of values for header. One for each list view.
        titleText.add("User Id Authentication");
        titleText.add("Android Posts Authentication");
        titleText.add("iOS Posts Authentication");
        titleText.add("Testing Posts Authentication");
        titleText.add("Java Posts Authentication");
        titleText.add("Dot Net Posts Authentication");
        titleText.add("OS Posts Authentication");
        titleText.add("HR Posts Authentication");
        titleText.add("Others Posts Authentication");




        SQLiteDataBaseAdapter db = new SQLiteDataBaseAdapter(this);
        List<String> childData =  db.getAndroidList();


        //setting the list adapter
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, titleText, childData);// this tells to implement some 8 methods, should I implement??

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_admin, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

I have so many expandable list views in one screen The array list is for the headers one for each expandable list view, the children will be again list of values from database. Please let me know how to use expandable list view in my case. I am very new to android and this is the first time I am working on Expandable List View. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find good tutorials for Expandable listview in the following link.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

You can remove unwanted header and child from the String List(based on Admin/User) before give it as input to Expandable list view adapter

Answer (score 0):

You should set adapter:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
    toolbar.setTitle(" Admin Screen");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    login = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewLogin);
    android = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewAndroid);
    ios = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewIos);
    testing = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewTesting);
    java = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewJava);
    dotNet = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewDotNet);
    os = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewOS);
    hr = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewHR);
    others = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewOthers);
    titleText.add("User Id Authentication");
    titleText.add("Android Posts Authentication");
    titleText.add("iOS Posts Authentication");
    titleText.add("Testing Posts Authentication");
    titleText.add("Java Posts Authentication");
    titleText.add("Dot Net Posts Authentication");
    titleText.add("OS Posts Authentication");
    titleText.add("HR Posts Authentication");
    titleText.add("Others Posts Authentication");
    SQLiteDataBaseAdapter db = new SQLiteDataBaseAdapter(this);
    List<String> childData =  db.getAndroidList();
    //setting the list adapter
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, titleText, childData);
    ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

}

Comment: I tried to do that, it asks me to implement some 8 methods should I do that? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
**Its Working**

package com.keshav.myexpandablelistviewexampleworkinginactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // tODO get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // TODO preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            // TODO Colapse Here Using this... in android
            int previousGroup = -1;
            boolean flag = false;

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

                Log.e("keshav", "onGroupClick is -> " + groupPosition);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (groupPosition != previousGroup && flag) {
                    expListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
                }
                previousGroup = groupPosition;

                flag = true;

            }
        });


        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


        // Todo Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Months");
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");


        // Adding child data
        List<String> weeks = new ArrayList<String>();
        weeks.add("Sunday");
        weeks.add("Monday");
        weeks.add("Tuesday");
        weeks.add("Wednesday");
        weeks.add("Thursday");
        weeks.add("Friday");
        weeks.add("Saturday");


        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("Om Shanti Om");
        top250.add("Badshah");
        top250.add("Bahubali Part 1");
        top250.add("Carry on Jatta");
        top250.add("Sholey");
        top250.add("Mard");
        top250.add("Dewwar");


        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("Bahubali");
        nowShowing.add("Kabali");
        nowShowing.add("Luckky Di Unlukky Story");
        nowShowing.add("Sachin Billions Dream");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("Tubelight ");
        comingSoon.add("Bahubali 3 2018");
        comingSoon.add("Dhoom 4");
        comingSoon.add("Hindi Medium");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), weeks);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), comingSoon);
    }
}



package com.keshav.myexpandablelistviewexampleworkinginactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // tODO get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // TODO preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            // TODO Colapse Here Using this... in android
            int previousGroup = -1;
            boolean flag = false;

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

                Log.e("keshav", "onGroupClick is -> " + groupPosition);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (groupPosition != previousGroup && flag) {
                    expListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
                }
                previousGroup = groupPosition;

                flag = true;

            }
        });


        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


        // Todo Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Months");
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");


        // Adding child data
        List<String> weeks = new ArrayList<String>();
        weeks.add("Sunday");
        weeks.add("Monday");
        weeks.add("Tuesday");
        weeks.add("Wednesday");
        weeks.add("Thursday");
        weeks.add("Friday");
        weeks.add("Saturday");


        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("Om Shanti Om");
        top250.add("Badshah");
        top250.add("Bahubali Part 1");
        top250.add("Carry on Jatta");
        top250.add("Sholey");
        top250.add("Mard");
        top250.add("Dewwar");


        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("Bahubali");
        nowShowing.add("Kabali");
        nowShowing.add("Luckky Di Unlukky Story");
        nowShowing.add("Sachin Billions Dream");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("Tubelight ");
        comingSoon.add("Bahubali 3 2018");
        comingSoon.add("Dhoom 4");
        comingSoon.add("Hindi Medium");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), weeks);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), comingSoon);
    }
}

activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4" >

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>   

</LinearLayout>

list_group.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" 
    android:background="#000000">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d" />

</LinearLayout>


list_item.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

</LinearLayout>
```